# C# Instance Name to Use For Network Interface Performance Counter

Tags: c#, wpf, performancecounter

I'm trying to add some system monitoring functions to a WPF app I am working on and I would like to add a bandwidth use monitor.  Right now I have a CPU and a RAM counter working but I can't figure out what to use for the Performance Counter instance name (sorry if that isn't the correct term).  This is what I'm using so far:

```
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
PerformanceCounter ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes", string.Empty);                        
PerformanceCounter netSentCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec", );
PerformanceCounter netRecCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Sent/sec", );
```

I have strings that update every 1 second using a timer tick method that updates my WPF labels and the RAM and the CPU counters work but I don't know what to put for the instance names for the last two network interfaces.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is some sample code how to iterate through the Network Interfaces;

```
    PerformanceCounterCategory category = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Network Interface");
    String[] instancename = category.GetInstanceNames();

    foreach (string name in instancename)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
```

By utilizing the **PerformanceCounterCategory**, you can now obtain the Instance Names, and then use in your PerformanceCounter(s) using **GetInstanceNames**.