# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll

Tags: c#

I was executing code below :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PerformanceCounter performanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Sent/sec", "Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection");
        Console.WriteLine(performanceCounter.NextValue().ToString());
    }
}
```

I'm getting this exception.

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: Instance 'Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection' does not exist in the specified Category.**

I have tested the parameters with windows perfmon tool , it was working but in code its giving exception.

Can anybody please help..

Comment: have you looked at the MSDN documentation for `PerformanceCounter` for examples on how to do what you are attempting to do..

Comment: have you install the driver fully??

Comment: Yes I have implemented this code with msdn guidelines... @alireza : what do you mean by fully installed?? I mentioned  that is is working in perfmon but not in code...

Comment: you know it might be from your .Net are you using a 3.0 or older ? it can make a problem

Comment: @alireza : I'm using .net framework 4.5...

Comment: @bakshay sorry i dont know any more :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if the name is spelled correctly? Even with a minor error, this most likely won't work.

To check which names exist in this category, try (as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29270209/1648463)

```
PerformanceCounterCategory category = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Network Interface");
String[] instancename = category.GetInstanceNames();

foreach (string name in instancename)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

For example, one of the existing names for network interfaces on my computer is

`Intel[R] 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection`

(with brackets instead of round brackets).

Comment: Works perfectly... with NetworkInterface class its giving NIC name as Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection , but parameter expecting '[R]' instead '(R)'.....

Comment: If this is the accepted answer, please do not forget to accept it - if it isn't, provide more data, please :)

Comment: For some reason the names returned from PerformanceCounterCategory use brackets, while the Descriptions from NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() uses parenthesis. The only sollution I have found is to use string replace, but it feels very dirty.

Comment: You could compare the names from PerformanceCounterCategory and descriptions / names from NetworkInterface with each other and take the one that is the most similar to the one you're looking for.
Be careful, though, since it can be either the name or description from the NetworkInterface.
What exactly are you looking to do with them?